# Entity Framework Database not Updating, No Errors

Tags: entity-framework

I've used `add-migration` and then `update-database` - both run with no errors, but the changes I am requesting to happen did not happen. I check my table data in the Server Explorer and it will not add the new column along with the other new data. I've attached my code if you need more of the code please let me know.

I did create another migration and copied the same changes to be added to the new changes to see if the new one would push. `Migrations/Update2.cs` and `Migrations/Update1.cs` are the same exact code.

```
//Migrations/Update2.cs "The updated Migration"

namespace EnrollmentApplication.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

    public partial class Update2 : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            AddColumn("dbo.Courses", "InstructorName", c => c.String());
            AddColumn("dbo.Enrollments", "Notes", c => c.String());
            AddColumn("dbo.Students", "Age", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
            AlterColumn("dbo.Courses", "CourseTitle", c => c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 150));
            AlterColumn("dbo.Courses", "CourseCredits", c => c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 4));
            AlterColumn("dbo.Enrollments", "Grade", c => c.String(nullable: false));
            AlterColumn("dbo.Enrollments", "AssignedCampus", c => c.String(nullable: false));
            AlterColumn("dbo.Enrollments", "EnrollmentSemester", c => c.String(nullable: false));
            AlterColumn("dbo.Students", "StudentFirstName", c => c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 50));
            AlterColumn("dbo.Students", "StudentLastName", c => c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 50));
        }

        public override void Down()
        {
            AlterColumn("dbo.Students", "StudentLastName", c => c.String());
            AlterColumn("dbo.Students", "StudentFirstName", c => c.String());
            AlterColumn("dbo.Enrollments", "EnrollmentSemester", c => c.String());
            AlterColumn("dbo.Enrollments", "AssignedCampus", c => c.String());
            AlterColumn("dbo.Enrollments", "Grade", c => c.String());
            AlterColumn("dbo.Courses", "CourseCredits", c => c.String());
            AlterColumn("dbo.Courses", "CourseTitle", c => c.String());
            DropColumn("dbo.Students", "Age");
            DropColumn("dbo.Enrollments", "Notes");
            DropColumn("dbo.Courses", "InstructorName");
        }
    }
}


//Models/Course.cs

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace EnrollmentApplication.Models
{
    public class Course : IValidatableObject
    {
        public virtual int CourseId { get; set; }
        [Required,]
        [StringLength(150)]
        public virtual string CourseTitle { get; set; }
        public virtual string CourseDescription { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(4), MinLength(1)]
        public virtual string CourseCredits { get; set; }

        public virtual string InstructorName { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            // Validation 1: Credits have to be between 1-4

            if(CourseDescription.Split (' ').Length > 100)
            {
                yield return (new ValidationResult("Your description is too verbose"));
            }

            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}

//Models/Enrollment.cs

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace EnrollmentApplication.Models
{
    public class Enrollment
    {
        public virtual int EnrollmentId { get; set; }
        public virtual int StudentId { get; set; }
        public virtual int CourseId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [RegularExpression("[A-F])")]
        public virtual string Grade { get; set; }
        public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
        public virtual Course Course { get; set; }
        public virtual bool IsActive { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public virtual int AssignedCampus { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public virtual string EnrollmentSemester { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public virtual int EnrollmentYear { get; set; }

        [RegularExpression(@"^[0-9a-zA-Z''-'\s]{1,40}$",
        ErrorMessage = "Invalid Characters")]
        public virtual string Notes { get; set; }
    }
}

//Models/Student.cs

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace EnrollmentApplication.Models
{
    public class Student
    {
        public virtual int StudentID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public virtual string StudentFirstName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public virtual string StudentLastName { get; set; }

        //MinimumAge(20)
        [MinimumAge(20)]
        public virtual int Age { get; set; }

        public virtual string Address1 { get; set; }
        public virtual string Address2 { get; set; }
        public virtual string City { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(5)]
        [MinLength(5)]
        [RegularExpression(@"^[0-9a-zA-Z''-'\s]{1,40}$",
        ErrorMessage = "Enter a 5 digit zipcode")]
        public virtual string Zipcode { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(2)]
        [MinLength(2)]
        [RegularExpression(@"^[0-9a-zA-Z''-'\s]{1,40}$",
        ErrorMessage = "Enter a 2 digit State code")]
        public virtual string State { get; set; }
    }
}
```

There's zero error messages but my changes are not applied.

Answer (score 0):

I had to Delete the Migrations folder, Delete the database in the Server Explorer, and in the Windows Explorer, delete my database in the App Data folder. Reloaded the application and built the new database and everything went through properly.